# OpenSQL syntax CASE statement in WHERE condition

Tags: abap, opensql

I would like to ask if it is possible to write CASE statement directly into WHERE clause (I know that WHERE clause can be passed also by string) e.g.

```
 SELECT * FROM db_table INTO TABLE @mt_table[]
     WHERE key1 = @l_key1
          AND key2 = @l_key2
          AND key3 = @l_key3
          AND key4 = @l_key4
          AND ( WHEN l_auth = 'A' THEN username = @sy-uname
                WHEN l_auth = 'U' THEN username = @sy-uname OR username = @space 
                END ).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use OR operator in WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM db_table INTO TABLE @mt_table[]
 WHERE key1 = @l_key1
   AND key2 = @l_key2
   AND key3 = @l_key3
   AND key4 = @l_key4
   AND ( ( l_auth = 'A' AND username = @sy-uname )
      OR ( l_auth = 'U' AND ( username = @sy-uname OR username= @space ) )
       ).
```

I didn't find any document for supporting case in where clause for Open Sql.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I need ! did not even realize such a solution is possible.